# Ruby require loop

Tags: ruby, decorator

I have the following code (simplified):

**decorator.rb**

```
require 'decoratable'

class Decorator < SimpleDelegator
  include Decoratable
end
```

**decoratable.rb**

```
require 'decorator_builder'

module Decoratable
  def decorate(*decorators)
    decorators.inject(DecoratorBuilder.new(self)) do |builder, decorator|
      builder.public_send(decorator)
    end.build
  end
end
```

**decorator_builder.rb**

```
require 'rare_decorator'

class DecoratorBuilder

  def initialize(card)
    @card = card
    @decorators = []
  end

  def rare
    @decorators << ->(card) { RareDecorator.new(card) }
    self
  end

  def build
    @decorators.inject(@card) do |card, decorator|
      decorator.call(card)
    end
  end

end
```

**rare_decorator.rb**

```
require 'decorator'

class RareDecorator < Decorator
  # Stuff here
end
```

When I require decorator.rb, it causes RareDecorator to be declared before Decorator is declared, which is a problem since RareDecorator inherits from Decorator.

A possible solution is to split up decorator.rb like so:

```
class Decorator < SimpleDelegator; end

require 'decoratable'

class Decorator
  include Decoratable
end
```

However, declaring dependencies in the middle of a file doesn't seem doesn't seem like a very clean solution to me.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Why does decorator require decoratable? That is the source of your problem (meaning you have a design problem).

Comment: Because I want both decorators, and the things being decorated, to include Decoratable. Then decorators can also be decorated, adding more decorators to the decorator chain. If the decorators didn't include Decoratable, then calling decorate on an already-decorated object would replace the decorators, instead of adding them. Sorry if I caused [semantic satiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation) of the word decorate :P

Comment: I agree that this setup would be indicative of a design problem, which is partially why I posted it, but I cannot see any other way of accomplishing the above without having this strange dependency loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of specifying requirements within every file, create one file which will require all the the application's requirements. Call it for example `environment.rb`:

```
require 'decoratable'
require 'decorator'
require 'decorator_builder'
require 'rare_decorator'
```

You don't need to worry about `Decoratable` not knowing what `DecoratorBuilder` is, as it is used within the method and the check for the constant will be executed when this method is called. Since you require decorator moment later, all will work.

Comment: Great, thanks :). I've always preferred declaring dependencies in each file, but now I see the advantage of having full control over load order of the files.

Comment: The downside to doing this is that it is much more difficult to package the decorator behavior in a gem, since any/all consumers of the gem will need a similar `environment.rb` file (or will need to require yours). The circular dependency still lives in the code, which hints at bad design.

Comment: I think IoC between DecoratorBuilder and RareDecorator would break this circular dependency. So DecoratorBuilder starts off with no knowledge of the decorators it can build, then RareDecorator registers its self with DecoratorBuilder when it is loaded. This way the code for decoration in no way depends on the concrete decorators, which seems like better design.